# Best algorithm to animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I made this script to animate a panel (open-close):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var z = '';
    $("#painel").hide()
    $(".btvagas").click(function () {
        z++;
        $("#painel").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
        if (z === 1) {
            $("#painel").animate({
                width: '400px'
            });
            $(".btvagas").animate({
                left: '336px'
            });
        } else {
            $(".btvagas").animate({
                left: '-65px'
            });
            z = 0;
        }
    })
});
```

You can see all the code with html and css here:
http://codepen.io/LuanPiegas/pen/wFyjG

But, I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript, so... there is a better way to do this, with the same result?

Comment: This would be more suitable at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Actually, the "best" way to animate for what you're looking to do is to use CSS3 transform. Not all browsers support it so you'll also need a fallback to jquery. Take a look at this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/ and this one: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `$("#painel")` and `$(".btvagas")` to variables so you don't have to call jQuery on them three times each.

```
var $painel = $('#painel'), $btvagas = $(".btvagas");
```

You can also use numbers instead of strings for the `width` and `left` properties since you're using pixels.

```
.animate({ left: 336 })
```

As for the algorithm itself. I don't think it's obvious enough what it does by looking at the code so it can definitely use some work. I'm brushing up for interviews so I wanted to give this pattern a try from scratch. Here is what I came up with. You can remove `.use-css-transitions` class from `.pulltab` element to use jQuery animations instead. I hope this helps!

http://jsbin.com/iSaPaNI/2/edit?js,output

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#foo').toggle(function(){
        $('#foobox').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 1000);
        $('#foobox').animate({marginLeft: '354'}, 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $('#foobox').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 1000);
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/tVekD/179/)**

Comment: [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: ...which is why it works in the fiddle only if jQuery 1.6 is selected. If you click on the OP's codepen link you'll see he uses 1.10.